# Ony the objects that are close appear in the rendered image

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I would like my render result to encompass all of the objects that I have created... I cant seem to get it to render anything at all! <strike>Also, I have UV unwrapped my shirt, and the texture shows up in texture mode, but not in render. Also, the physics for the cloth material do not work.</strike>

I am new to blender and am very excited, but cant seem to get this working. Here is my blend file, any help is appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17b401ZM6nmej-8338dt_0ztc9xH58xaJ

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. You have three completely different question in there. For any blends please use [blend exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Please edit this question, remove two of your other questions (you can ask as many questions as you want) and add more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You have a scene where things are huge. The room is more than 200 meters long, the TV is larger than a theater screeen, the chair will only be good for giants like the one in your scene...

Then, your camera is set to have a clipping point of 10cm to 100m. Any object that is closer or further away than than the clipping distance will be ignored.

[image]

Increase the clipping distance so that it can display objects in the distance.

[image]

But as a piece of unwanted advice: in Blender it is better to work in a scale that matches the real world. Physics, and other simulations, depth of field and lighting will behave differently depending on the scale.